# Is it possible for Chapter One to be on page 1 immediately after toc?

Tags: latex, tableofcontents, page-numbering, overleaf

I am typing a book on Overleaf. I used \frontmatter and \mainmatter commands to influence page numbering however the final page of TOC ends up on page 1 making the first Chapter start on page 2. Additionally, even though, Chapter One is on page 2, the TOC indicates it's on page 1 but the first section is on page 2(Odd). I even tried manually numbering the pages using \pagenumbering{..} but that didn't work. I also googled similar issues but nothing worked. I have included links to snips of my project in case my code is wrong. I have two requests;

1. For all TOC pages to be roman numbered(i, ii,..) and Chapter One to start on page 1 with no blank page between TOC and Chapter One. The no blank page is a preference, not a must.
2. The TOC to show Chapter One is on its current page, not the previous one. Also, if someone knows how to modify the displayed page(s) on TOC, please share too. That will greatly help.

Thank you.

Links:
Preamble: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16_Nk1blzZualeooFblI28Yknn4QrPUQS/view?usp=sharing

Chapter: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-K08x4jZce8zYAuwudTblhDs5MQIv-OH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please add a compilable [mre] to your question